# How does std swap deduce the length of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, swap

Here is the case of using std::swap to interchange values of two arrays.

```
int arr1[3]={1,2,3};
int arr2[3]={4,5,6};
std::swap(arr1,arr2);
//Then arr1 becomes {4,5,6} and arr2 becomes {1,2,3}
```

The swap function is declared as

```
template <class T, size_t N> void swap(T (&a)[N], T (&b)[N])
  noexcept (noexcept(swap(*a,*b)));
```

I am curious about the mechanisms of the `size_t N` deduction, how is it accomplished? Since a pointer of an int array doesn't have any information about its length.

Comment: Arrays aren't pointers. Arrays carry their size information and arrays are what are passed into the function.

Comment: `int *` and `int[3]` and `int[4]` are different types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *reference to array* is only allowed to bind to an array of the correct extent. For example a `int (&)[10]` cannot bind to an `int` array of size other than 10, nor can it bind to an `int*`. This is also true when you have a parameter of reference to array type.

When you pass an array to a function and the parameter is not a reference, the argument is decayed to a pointer to the array's first element. But when you pass an array by reference, for the purposes of template parameter deduction, the argument type is *not* decayed. This is because a reference to array parameter can't bind to a pointer. Since the argument type isn't decayed, the template parameter `N` can be correctly deduced.